# C++ debugger stopped working in VS Code with WMI error

Tags: visual-studio-code

After a windows update and visual studio update to 1.75.1, I am unable to use the debugger C++ debugger with the following error:

```
 Error: "pwsh -NoProfile -Command "Get-CimInstance Win32_Process | Select-Object Name,ProcessId,CommandLine | ConvertTo-JSON -Compress"" exited with code: "1".

Get-CimInstance: Invalid class
```

I see the same error when I try `Get-CimInstance Win32_Process` in PowerShell.

Tried reinstalling Windows PowerShell, searched for windows updates, switched to older version of Visual Studio Code and tried a clean install. Also tried to check WMI repository and it seems to be consistent.